Why does the Hotellings T-Squared Statistic scale by a factor of n?
According to the NIST: https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section5/pmc543.htm the equation for a T-Squared statistic has a scaling factor of n (Interestingly, the Wikipedia page for this references this page, but omits the n scaling factor). (I misread, the factor is included in the sample covariance calc.)
I was wondering why this scaling factor is included? Is there any intuition behind it?
Does this mean that as the number of samples increases, the likelihood of an identical sample that is being tested causes us to reject the null hypothesis increases?
I am imagining 2-D multivariate normal data as the sample, with maybe n=100 and n=1000 (sampled from the same true distribution). These would have (close to) identical sample means and variances, but because of this n factor, the likelihood that a new sample from this distribution fails the null hypothesis increases as n increases?
Of course, as n increases the relation to a F distribution (what we use to check) changes, but not by much. For p=2, the scaling of T^2 (n-p)/(pn-p) is 98/198 ~ 1/2 for n=100 and 998/1998 ~ 1/2 for n=1000, and the F critical value for alpha=0.05 is ~3 for both, so they would have little effect.

Welcome to Cross Validated! The univariate analogue of this is a t-test of means, and the t-stat depends on the sample size, right?
